# Is it possible to run in parallel mode integration tests written in Spock Framework for Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, integration-testing, spock, maven-failsafe-plugin

Base Spock specification is:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationTestConfig.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource("/application.properties")
abstract class SpringBootTestSpecification extends Specification {
```

Project is building by maven 3.3.9 with failsafe-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*SpecIT.java</include>
                </includes>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I want to run my test in parallel mode but I want to be sure that one won't affect others (application runs with embedded DB and prepares different data for different tests).

Answer (score -1):

If the embedded DB would be the same (same file / url / name) for every test, even though it probably gets truncated or recreated, parallelize the tests might not work as expected as one test might be running while another might attempt to reseed the data.

If somehow each test connects to a unique DB, my guess is that tests could be parallelized.

http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

Make sure JUnit4 is configured to parallelize them by method, class, etc..

And if you feel curious, a few months ago I published a blog post [Integration Testing using Spring Boot, Postgres and Docker](http://tech.asimio.net/2016/08/04/Integration-Testing-using-Spring-Boot-Postgres-and-Docker.html) where each test connects to a `Postgres` DB running in a different container. I don't remember covering running the tests in parallel but that would be doable.

Comment: You could just design your tests so that they don't truncate or recreate the database. It's perfectly feasible to make sure they don't make assumptions on being the sole test being executed: don't rely on fixed IDs but explicitely use the ones that the test created, don't assume anything about the last thing inserted, don't expect a table to exactly contain some rows etc.

Comment: @ymajoros, if you don't know the state of the DB, what would you assert against?
You said: "don't rely on fixed IDs but explicitely use the ones that the test created". That means a test that selects data now depends on a previous test that inserted it. Your are imposing test order and the select-related test will fail not because any logic with selecting, but because insertion-related test failed. That's a very poor design.

Comment: No, in fact, it exactly means the opposite. A test that selects data should create its own dataset and not rely on any other one. You actually don't know the state of the DB and shouldn't make any assumption regarding it.

Comment: @ymajoros and now for testing a select the test itself becomes verbose and complex because you first need to save data, when you have 50 tables and dozen joins, good luck keeping the test simple and readable.

Comment: So, your test now has a setup method. No big deal.

Comment: @ymajoros. Not necessarily. Nothing wrong with setup() method btw.
Integration tests use something like
@SqlGroup({
    @Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = { "classpath:schema.sql", "classpath:data.sql" }),
    @Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:purge.sql")
})
then each test don't need to seed the DB in the test method.

Easier to maintain, easy to add more tests, easier to refactor when DB evolves, and DB will evolve.

Comment: Nothing wrong with a setup method, that's what I meant too. If you purge the db after each call, you cannot run tests in parallel. My point was that tests should only modify their own data. I do run tests massively in parallel, it's just some discipline that you must have.